# Showing specific columns from sqlite3 database on Tkinter list

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Customer Database: `Tel No, Name, PostCode, Address`

I want to show ONLY Tel No and Address on Tkinder list

I have the following code:

```
def read_customerData():
    connCustomer = sqlite3.connect('customerData.db')
    cCustomer = connCustomer.cursor()
    cCustomer.execute('SELECT * FROM customerData')
    for row in cCustomer.fetchall()
        listBoxCus.insert(tk.END, row[0], row[3])
```

But it is showing:

```
Tel No
Address
Tel No
Address
.
.
.
```

Instead of:

```
Tel No  Address
Tel No  Address
.
.
```

I tried `row[0] + row[3]` but it is showing some error.

Comment: The listbox widget is documented to only support one column.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I'll just add another listbox into that frame then.